# SQLConnection bringing data to TextBox

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms, connection-string

I know this looks really simple but i've been looking for an answer for hours with no luck.

I want to fill my row values into a bunch of textboxes. How can I specify that `[CompanyName]` is going to be used by the `companyName` textbox? Please keep it as simple as possible (beginner level).

```
string customerUniqueID = "test";

string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnection"].ToString(); // connection string
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
con.Open();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Customers] WHERE [UniqueID] = @UniqueID", con); // table name 
com.Parameters.Add("@UniqueID", SqlDbType.Int);
com.Parameters["@UniqueID"].Value = customerUniqueID;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
companyName.Text = ?????????
```

Comment: `[CompanyName]` is from database ? and can there be multiple rows for `WHERE [UniqueID] = @UniqueID` ? if so will it be okay to set first row's data into textbox ?

Comment: yes that is my column name!

Comment: @ConstantinosTillits have you successfully query into database ?

Comment: no multiple rows. UniqueID is my unique identifier!

Comment: there are 10 columns in my table and 10 textboxes on my page and i would like to use them all... i was thinking about filling my textboxes one by one repeating the companyName textbox process 10 times

Comment: Resolved ! Thank you all for your fast responses!!

Comment: @ConstantinosTillits Also please mark as answer one of the answers, which you think answers to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
string customerUniqueID = "test";

string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnection"].ToString(); // connection string
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
con.Open();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Customers] WHERE [UniqueID] = @UniqueID", con); // table name 
com.Parameters.Add("@UniqueID", SqlDbType.Int);
com.Parameters["@UniqueID"].Value = customerUniqueID;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "Customers");

companyName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CompanyName"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend some changes in your code:

1. Your sql query returning result from one set, so you can use `DataTabe` instead of `DataSet`.
2. To fill results from DB to your `DataTable` you can use [`SqlAdapter.Fill()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.fill(v=vs.110).aspx).
3. Use [`Field()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field(v=vs.90).aspx) generic method (more [examples of `Field()`](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datarow-field)) to get values from your `DataTable`.
4. Use `using` blocks for disposable objects, or at least make sure you've closed them after.
5. There is no need of `con.Open()` to open connection when using `Fill()` method, because from MSDN:

> The Fill method implicitly opens the Connection that the DataAdapter is using if it finds that the connection is not already open. If Fill opened the connection, it will also close the connection when Fill is finished. This can simplify your code when dealing with a single operation such as a Fill or an Update.

```
string customerUniqueID = "test";
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnection"].ToString(); // connection string
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand();
    com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Customers] WHERE [UniqueID] = @UniqueID";
    com.Parameters.Add("@UniqueID", SqlDbType.Int);
    com.Parameters["@UniqueID"].Value = customerUniqueID;
    using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        companyName.Text = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("CompanyName");
    }
}
```

Please feel free to comment, if I missed something.